# Constrain jQuery nestedSortable items (that's being dragged) within container?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, nested-sortable

I'm looking into if it's possible to have nestedSortable items to be force kept within it's container while items are being dragged. As it is now, if you grab an item and pull it sideways you'll be able to drag it, basically, offscreen if you want. I'm wondering if it's possible to restrict this in someway?

Here's a video on how I want it to function:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3618143/drag.mov

And here's a demo (try to drag horizontally and you'll see what I mean):
http://jsfiddle.net/uzRGB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-containment ...?

EDIT: now with updated fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/uzRGB/2/

Comment: @Matheletics I still need to utilize that nesting functionality from nestedSortable. So I need to be able to drag items sideways, BUT if I drag an item 10px to the right, I don't want it sticking out 10px on the other side.

Comment: no, I mean you can supply the containment options to nestedSortable: http://jsfiddle.net/uzRGB/1/

Comment: Oh, sweet! Works kind of as I'd like it. It's a little bit confusing when you're nesting, since it doesn't show visually that it will nest under another item, do you think it's possible to find a solution there?

Edit: Also somewhat problematic when there's no nested items at all: http://jsfiddle.net/59yNM/

Comment: you just can't have the items take up the whole width; otherwise there's nowhere for them to go. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/59yNM/3/ you can now drag and drop to the right to nest.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to have the items shrink in width while dragging them to the right. The example you posted now is pretty much what I began with if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6007/discussion-between-mathletics-and-int)